# Pass URL to get user information using tweepy python

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I would like to get the information using url link (for example, https://twitter.com/BillGates). I could get the info using the screen_name, for example:

```
CONSUMER_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
OAUTH_TOKEN = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
user_data = api.get_user(screen_name="@BillGates") # to get the user info
posts = api.user_timeline(screen_name="@BillGates", count = 150, tweet_mode="extended") # to get the last 150 tweets.
```

But I would like to pass the url link to get user time line information or the tweets. Please help!

Comment: get url `https://twitter.com/BillGates` and remove `https://twitter.com/` to get only `BillGates` and use it with your current code. It needs standard string functions - ie.`url.replace("https://twitter.com/", "")`

Answer (score -1):

I can not understand why you need to pass the url link directly to fetch the information. I guess you could preprocess the url to figure out the screen_name. For example, simply parsing the url to remove the  https://twitter.com/ part of the string.

Comment: I have already tried that. But this approach is not working for some cases. Unfortunately I can't provide the example.

Comment: @user3642360 use `print()` to get urls which make problem and then create new question with examples. And then we can try to create solution.